# How can I make the monospace font narrower using fontspec?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, typewriter

The available monospace fonts are mostly too wide for convenient use in documenting code (Courier is an extreme example). Although narrower fonts exist (Prestige Elite, and zcoN, a narrowed Courier), they are mostly based on 10cpi designs, or they may not go well with the body font, or may lack variants such as bold and italic.

I can scale a monospace font in both height and width with `fontspec`’s Scale parameter, but it only accepts a single decimal value (or the Match instructions). What I want to do is to *narrow* the font, so that it keeps its height but is slightly squeezed horizontally. I have tested what I want, using the `\scalebox` command, so I am satisfied that it won't appear too distorted.

Is there any way to achieve this in XeLaTeX, or will I have to created some modified font files?

Answer (score 6):

See 6.7 Font transformations in the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Courier \addfontfeature{FakeStretch=0.5} Courier
\end{document}
```

[image]